# Namespace and Using with 'System' in it

Tags: c#, namespaces, using-directives

I have a library - `Foo.System.Management`

I have an application - `Foo.New.Application`

In this application, `Using System;` is imported, and what ends up happening is this is being resolved to `Foo.System` and causes my project to throw error's saying

> The type or namespace `Diagnostics` does not exist in the namespace `Foo.System`

My assumption is that because of the same Base namespace `Foo` it is causing that resolution. Looking through the [Namespace Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces) I can't really find a clear explanation of this.

- What are my options in my `Foo.New.Application`?
- Some of those `Using System;` directives are code generated so I cannot control aliasing. Should I just rename the library?
- Is it bad practice to create a namespace like `Foo.System` for that reason?

Comment: I don't think I'd ever include `System` in one of my namespaces - if it confuses me, it's like to confuse the compiler.  But, you can usually fix weird namespace issues by using the alias feature of the `using` keyword.  Something like `using Management = Foo.System.Management;`.  It may take some experimentation to get it right (and comfortable in your use case)

Comment: @Flydog57 right, the alias will work for me, but like I said... some code generation imports cause the conflicts. The reason I named my library `System` was because I abstracted some general `System` functions that we use

Comment: Can you influence/configure the code generation in a way that it places the `using System;` directive outside any namespace declaration? Because then the using directive would sit in global namespace scope, with the closest "System" namespace the global::System namespace. Or can you configure the code generation to always generate using directives with the absolute namespace name rooted in global, i.e., `using global::System;` instead of just `using System;`?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace not really familiar with how to influence the code generation. It is a WPF application and it is the `File.g.cs` files that are throwing the errors

Comment: Wait, doesn't the code generator for .g.cs files not place the using directives outside of the namespace declarations anymore? (I only have old .NET Framework WPF projects here i can look at, and for those the generated .g.cs files have the using directives outside any namespace declarations.) Are you sure you are having a problem with using directives and not just with some fully qualified type names like System.SomeTypeName or System.Blah.SomeOtherTypeName within the generated code?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace So it does place the using directives Outsite of the namespace, but within the namespace it references the libraries like `System.Diagnostics` which is getting resolved to `Foo.System.Diagnostics`. I just renamed my library, re-imported, and all those errors went away

Comment: Rant/FYI: Yeah, it's not the using directive then, but the fully qualified type names that give you grief. Interestingly, the code generator for the Ressources and old-style Settings classes actually uses global:: for the fully qualified type names. Not that it helps you in any way with the generated *.g.cs code, but evidently the team behind developing the generator for the Ressources/Settings *.designer.cs files was acutely aware of possible namespace resolution conflicts. Well, it seems that team unfortunately didn't have a hand in doing the generator for the *.g.cs files :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing the design guidelines:

> ❌ DO NOT introduce generic type names such as Element, Node, Log, and
> Message.
>
> There is a very high probability that doing so will lead to type name
> conflicts in common scenarios. You should qualify the generic type
> names (FormElement, XmlNode, EventLog, SoapMessage).

> Core namespaces include all System namespaces, excluding namespaces of the application models and the Infrastructure namespaces. Core namespaces include, among others, **System**, System.IO, System.Xml, and System.Net.
>
> ❌ DO NOT give types names that would conflict with any type in the
> Core namespaces.
>
> For example, never use Stream as a type name. It would conflict with
> System.IO.Stream, a very commonly used type.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces

So, yes, you should find a more suitable name for your library that follows the design guidelines for names of namespaces and it is indeed bad practice to use `System` as part of your namespace name.